# How to represent Array using fieldset in angular template driven form model

Tags: angular6

I have a form which is having nested objects array. For representing multi level form view model we are using ngModelGroup with which we can map parent child relation. Is there a way to represent array using a directive something similar to ngModelGroup?

below are the models,

```
export class SurveyViewModel {
Survey: Survey;
QuestionAnswerSets: QuestionAnswerSet[];
}

export class Survey {
Id: string;
Name: string;   
}


export class QuestionAnswerSet {
Question: Question;
Answers: Answer[];
}
```

below is the view,

```
  <form [formGroup]="surveyForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(surveyForm)">

      <div formGroupName="Survey">
        <input type="hidden" name="Id" formControlName="Id">
        <label>{{model.Survey.Name}}</label>
      </div>

      <div class='qa-set' formArrayName="QuestionAnswerSets">
        <fieldset *ngFor="let questionAnswerSet of surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets.controls; index as setId;" [formGroupName]="setId">
          <div formGroupName="Question">

            <input type="hidden" name="Id" formControlName="Id">
            <label>{{setId+1}}. </label>
            <label>{{model.QuestionAnswerSets[setId].Question.Value}}</label>
          </div>

          <div class="row" formArrayName="Answers">
            <div *ngFor="let answer of this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets.controls[setId].controls.Answers.controls; index as answerId;"
              [formGroupName]="answerId">

              <div class="col-12 col-sm-3" formGroupName="Answer">
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" formControlName="Id">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="Value" formControlName="Value" /> {{model.QuestionAnswerSets[setId].Answers[answerId].Value}}
                </label>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why don't you use Reactive Form with FormArray?

Comment: As i get my survey and its related questions from database template binding is easy and clear.

Comment: Reactive form is easy to populate as well what you need to you is just this.surveyForm.patchValue(nested_object_from_db) just need to be sure that reactive form structure equals to db returned object

Comment: @Timothy reason for not using reactive forms is simple: less code and usually much cleaner TS, no ballast to pull/push data (why to have a framework if you need to code everything?)! Also that's the real angular way (also Aurelia way), etc. There's more template driven frameworks than react driven, guess why?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can do it with FormArray

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  Validators,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormArray
} from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {
  public surveyForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(protected formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Survey: new FormGroup({
        Id: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        Name: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
      }),
      QuestionAnswerSets: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  initSet() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      Question: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      Answers: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  addSet() {
    const questionAnswerSets = <FormArray>(
      this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets
    );
    questionAnswerSets.push(this.initSet());
  }

  removeSet(setId: number) {
    let questionAnswerSets = <FormArray>(
      this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets
    );
    questionAnswerSets.removeAt(setId);
  }

  initAnswer() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      Answer: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
    });
  }

  addAnswer(setId: number) {
    const questionAnswerSets = <FormArray>(
      this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets
    );
    const answer = <FormArray>(
      questionAnswerSets.controls[setId]["controls"].Answers
    );
    answer.push(this.initAnswer());
  }

  removeAnswer(setId: number, answerId: number) {
    const questionAnswerSets = <FormArray>(
      this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets
    );
    const answer = <FormArray>(
      questionAnswerSets.controls[setId]["controls"].Answers
    );
    answer.removeAt(answerId);
  }
}
```

teamplate

```
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm" (ngSubmit)="saveForm(surveyForm.value)">
    <div formArrayName="QuestionAnswerSets">
        <fieldset *ngFor="let questionAnswerSet of surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets.controls; index as setId;" [formGroupName]="setId">
            <input type="text" formControlName="Question" />
            <div formArrayName="Answers">
                <div class="ui-g-12" *ngFor="let answer of this.surveyForm.controls.QuestionAnswerSets.controls[setId].controls.Answers.controls; index as answerId;"
                    [formGroupName]="answerId">
                    <input type="text" formControlName="Answer" />
                    <button type="button" (click)="removeAnswer(setId, answerId)">Remove Answer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" (click)="addAnswer(setId)">Add Answer</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addSet()">Add Set</button>
</form>
```

Probably I've missed something, but it will give you an idea

Comment: My requirement is i should just post a list questions and their answers along with some survey realted data.

Comment: This is just an example. Not complete solution. But according to my experience reactive forms is better when it comes to dynamic data structure.

Comment: How we can distinguish 'name' of each answer in list? Ex: if there are4 questions and each has 4 answers all 16 answers will have radio button with same name. How i can handle this?

Comment: Hi @Timothy , I have updated code.please let me know if u  get any idea. thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Replace name="Value" formControlName="Value" with name [name]="setId" only so the radio grouped properly (in survey.component.html, line 34). 'name' defines the group of the radio and must be persistent within a group. If this is what you want

Answer (score 4):

After reading so many articles on nested models template driven forms and official angular documentation i could say this can not be done using template driven forms as there no directive which represents an array. (grouping as how fieldset does for an object with ngModelGroup)

This could be done with angular reactive forms with FormArrayName

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName

Comment: This is sad, not remembering AngularJS having such a constraint! The problem is that we need the extra directive just inside ngFrom.valueChange, cause otherwise (after value change the binding does the things right)...

Comment: See the git hub issue
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615

Answer (score 0):

You could still use Template Driven Form with ngModelGroup to build the form template and iterate over an array (to generate the input fields).

The internal data representation inside ngModelGroup is an Object.

To access the ngModelGroup value as an array you could to this (e.g. on submit):

```
submit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('form data', form.value);

    // Convert ngModelGroup Object to Array
    const resourcesFormGroup: AbstractControl = form.control.get('resources');
    const resources: Resource[] = Object.keys(resourcesFormGroup.value).map(item => {
        return resourcesFormGroup.value[item];
    });

    console.log('form data fixed', {
        ...form.value,
        resources
    });
}
```

That's not elegant, but works :)